# Preventing page break in register between reference and page number (ConTeXt)

Tags: page-breaking, context, indexing

Problem: The page number of an reference in the register is set to th next page - pake breaking between the reference and the page number.

I do not know how to produce a smaller Example:

```
\definepapersize[MyBook][A6]
\setuppapersize[MyBook][A6] % Prints on paper the size of MyBook

\starttext     
\index{A} blub
\index{B} blub
\index{C} blub
\index{D} blub
\index{E} blub
\index{F} blub
\index{G} blub
\index{H} blub
\index{I} blub
\index{J} blub
\index{K} blub
\index{Long Long Long} blub
\index{M} blub
\index{N} blub

\completeindex
\stoptext
```

The page numer of the reference "Long Long Long" is set to the next page. How to prevent this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you can still use this answer or if there have been comments that solved your problem before. But I am putting this here to lessen the number of unanswered questions. Well, I am new to `Context` but for your problem, you can consider shortening the distance between index entry and the page number using

```
\setupregister[index][balance=yes,distance=6pt]
```

in your setup area.

Here is the full code:

```
\definepapersize[MyBook][A6]
\setuppapersize[MyBook][A6] % Prints on paper the size of MyBook
\setupregister[index][distance=6pt]

\starttext     
\index{A} blub
\index{B} blub
\index{C} blub
\index{D} blub
\index{E} blub
\index{F} blub
\index{G} blub
\index{H} blub
\index{I} blub
\index{J} blub
\index{K} blub
\index{Long Long Long} blub
\index{M} blub
\index{N} blub

\completeindex
\stoptext
```